# Method parameter range

Tags: c#, methods, attributes

I am looking for an Attribute-written-code to specify the parameter range such as it works on a property. I need it on a method.

Analogy which exists (and works) for a property:

```
[Range(0,10)]
public int MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

Is there any analogy for a method? (below is my pseudocode):

```
[Range(0,10,"MyParameter")]
public void MyMethod(int MyParameter){...}
```

I know that there is the alternative

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
```

but I am asking for alternative in Attribute.

Any help?

Comment: No, you can't do it with *just* an attribute.

Comment: OK, thanx. But how to do it in a constructor? It is impossible to use throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

Comment: `RangeAttribute` does not force .NET to fire an exception whever the range is exceeded. It is **used** for something similar though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax would look a bit like this:

```
public void MyMethod([Range(0,10)] int myParameter)
{
    ...
}
```

And thankfully, the built-in [`RangeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute) supports `AttributeTargets.Parameter`, so this will compile. However, whether or not this is enforced depends *entirely* on how this is used. You'll need some kind of validation framework that checks the parameter for a valid range. The .NET framework will not do this for you automatically on all method calls.

Comment: It looks great, but what a pity that it is not working without any validation.

Answer (score 0):

Existing solutions that allow this:

```
public void MyMethod([Range(0, 10)] int MyParameter) { ... }
```